# Qt / QMake iOS Set Target, Device, other XCode settings

Tags: ios, qt, qmake

Qt for iOS creates an XCode project when you execute a build.

How does one dictate the XCode project settings from Qt to set a "target" (minimum iOS version) and "device" (Universal/iPhone/iPad), as found on the "General" tab in XCode when this project is opened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not find this documented anywhere, but I figured it out.

In your qmake (pro or pri file) add these lines:

```
# Set "Target"
QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 5.0

# Set "Devices" (2=iPad Only)
QMAKE_IOS_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 2
```

Note for devices: 1=iPhone, 2=iPad, 1,2=Universal.

If you need to change other XCode project settings here's how you can:

After a build in Qt for iOS look at the "Compile Output" tab.
You will find a list of "export VARIBALE=some_value" entries.
To change one of these XCode build settings, simply use QMAKE_IOS_VARIABLE_NAME = my_value in your qmake.

For more info on these environmental varibles, check this out: [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW51)

-- UPDATE --

I was wrong about the last part.  You can't set all the XCode variables quite like that.  If you output QMAKESPEC, however, you will get the path where you can find a qmake.conf file which will display some of these undocumented variables.  Do so like this in your pro / pri:

```
  message( $$QMAKESPEC )
```

That path will appear in the Qt console "General" tab when you build the project.

Here's an extended version I'm now using, with some logic for setting the build architectures:

```
greaterThan( QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5 ){
   DEFINES += QT_VER_5_4_OR_NEWER
}
else:equals( QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5 ) &&
    greaterThan( QT_MINOR_VERSION, 3 ){
    DEFINES += QT_VER_5_4_OR_NEWER
}

contains(DEFINES, QT_VER_5_4_OR_NEWER){
    DEFINES += SUPPORT_64_BIT_IOS
    message( "SUPPORT_64_BIT_IOS" )
}

contains(DEFINES, SUPPORT_64_BIT_IOS) {
    iosArchitectures="armv7 arm64"
    iosTarget=5.1.1
}
else{
    iosArchitectures=armv7
    iosTarget=5.0
}

# Set "Architectures"
QMAKE_IOS_DEVICE_ARCHS = $$iosArchitectures

# Set "Target"
QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = $$iosTarget

# Set "Devices" (1=iPhone, 2=iPad, 1,2=Universal)
QMAKE_IOS_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 2
```